# QuantumInstance object has no attribute "name"

Tags: programming, qiskit

I follow qiskit tutorial "Portfolio optimization". When I executed this cell, I encounter the attribute error as the title(picture showed below).
[image]

Do anyone know how to fix this problem?
It seems like the problem is inside the package, so I have no idea...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think that technical Qiskit questions such as this should be issues on Qiskit's GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message stated, `QuantumInstance` has no attribute `name`.

What it has is `backend` and from `backend` you can retrieve `name`.

For example:

```
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend=Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator'))
quantum_instance.backend
```

will printout:

```
StatevectorSimulator('statevector_simulator')
```

and if you do

```
quantum_instance.backend.name()
```

it will printout

```
'statevector_simulator'
```